# how to display variable on smarty tpl

Tags: variables, smarty

this is my tpl code 
the {$video_link} when i use it with other (meta or FB: like etc) it work normal 
inf fact in html code source page they display the coorect url ( seo)
but this scirpt don't

```
    {literal}<script>
  function postlike()
  {
     FB.api(
  'me/video.watches',
  'post',
  {
    video : "{$video_link}"
  },
        function(response) {
           if (!response || response.error) {
              alert('Post was not published.');
           } else {
              alert('Post was published. Action ID: ' + response.id);
           }
        });
  }
  </script>{/literal}
```

normally they must be

```
  'post',
  {
    video: "http://zdig1.biz/video/one-piece/611-video_942e07e26.html"
  },
```

but on page still appear

```
video : "{$video_link}"
```

so i thinked that my be there is a proble on the { before the $ !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution

```
{ video : "{/literal}{$video_link}{literal}" },`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using smarty 3, just remove the {literal} tag and it should work fine. If not, and you don't want to be opening and closing literal tags, declare all the variables you need outside the literal section ie:

```
<script>
var video_link = "{$video_link}";

{literal}

function postlike()
  {...

    video : video_link
```